# Book where the main character trapped in a well has dragon blood dripping onto him and he slowly turns into one

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

Looking for a particular book. I read it almost 10 years ago.

The main character gets trapped in a (well?) and dragon’s blood drips onto him. The blood slowly turns him into a dragon (Or gives him dragon-like qualities) over several years. I remember thinking the book to place in a more medieval setting.  At some point the MC is living in the attic of a brothel...

Comment: Possibly this answer (mine) to another question? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91807/46643

Comment: Until the last sentence, I wondered if you’d remembered the reverse of that scene in *The Voyage of the Dawn Trader* where Aslan turns Eustace back into a boy from a dragon... but, ah, no...

Comment: In Robin Hobb's Rain Wild books dragon blood can gradually give you dragon traits, but I don't recall any scene where a character is trapped with dragon blood dripping onto them.

Comment: try "A Study of Dragons, East and West by Qiguang Zhao".

Comment: @Kipz: You can accept Moriarty's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

This is Lawrence Watt-Evans' [*Obsidian Chronicles trilogy*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/498139.Dragon_Weather?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=9nRbkvb5qu&rank=1): *Dragon Weather*, *Dragon Society* and *Dragon Venom*.

[image: front cover of Dragon Society showing a dragon in front of a mountain]

The story opens with the MC's family/village killed by a dragon, which drips venom on him while he's hiding from it. He wants vengeance but is surprised to find out at the end of book 1, many years later, that being dripped on by a dragon is how dragons are created, and that he is going to become one.

> “Dragons destroyed my home village,” he said. “At least three of them. They came nine years ago, during a long spell of dragon weather. I was in the family cellar, taking inventory to see how much we needed to add before winter, when they attacked. My grandfather was killed by a blast of venom that failed to ignite, and he fell down the cellar ladder onto me as he died; his blood, and the venom, spilled into my mouth as I lay stunned beneath his corpse.”

And yes, eventually he lives in the attic of a brothel.

> “Where am I?” he said. “Who are you?” He wanted to ask why she had seduced him, as well,
> but couldn’t think of any decent way to phrase it.
> “You’re in the House of Carnal Society,” she told
> him.
> “The what? ” he asked.
> She giggled. “It’s a brothel, silly! Hadn’t you
> guessed?”
> Arlian looked at her in embarrassed confusion.
> “What’s a brothel?” he asked.

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail about how the plot matches?

Comment: Done. I meant to add more detail initially but got distracted by life.

Comment: Pfft. Life. You need to let your friends and family know that you can't get deal with their nonsense right now because you've more important things to do.

Comment: Moriarty, I started writing up an answer before getting distracted by dinner (I know... life, right?). Feel free to mine any of the quotes and links you'd like.